# Catching an exception

Tags: c#, exception

I'm currently getting an exception thrown and the message it gives is Value does not fall within the expected range. I'm trying to right a piece of code to grab this exception and suppress it - I know what the issue is - essentially someone is trying to pull a record from a list using an id which doesn't exist.

Any ideas how i go about catching this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: You should use `try-catch`, but also you need the handle the error with code. For example, if you're reading an array, and you go too far, through your code you should not let it do it, and you should stop when the array does not have any more elements. The `try-catch` should be used for exceptions generated by the user, not by the code.

Comment: You should at least log the exception somewhere. exceptions are not thrown for fun.

Comment: The simplest way to suppress an Exception is: `try { //code } catch { }` But it's usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suppress an exception you need to do something like this

```
try
{
     // Code that may throw an exception.
}
catch (Exception ex) // Better to use a more specific exception class
{
    // Do nothing - That suppresses the exception.

    // If you want to do additional checking that may continue the exception
    // up the stack use "throw" on its own - which compiled to CIL/MSIL's
    // "rethrow" and doesn't drop much of the information that would
    // go if you did "throw ex"
}
```

That's all there is to suppressing an exception.

For the sanity of those that have to maintain this code (or yourself in 6 months time when you've forgotten the specifics of why you did this), it would also be good to comment exactly why you are suppressing the exception. If I see code that suppresses an exception I always want to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try` `catch` block with an empty `catch` ?

if you want to get really specific you can use an exception filter to catch only that case (in c# 6 of course).